# How to scale text to height of TextView but wrap content horizontally

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a fixed height in `dp` and `layout_width="wrap_content"` for my `TextView`, and the `textSize` in `sp`. I do not want a fixed text size (due to variable screen density), and rather I would like the text to scale vertically to the fixed view bounds, and for the `TextView` width to wrap to the text. I tried using `autoSizeTextType="uniform"` but the text started wrapping to the next line, which was weird. Has anyone been able to accomplish this vertical scaling with `layout_width="wrap_content"` for the `TextView`?

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:text="Some Text"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_tag_name"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"`?
Using `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` only works on API level 26 or higher.

One more thing, try to use `android:maxLines="1"`.

I recommend you to have a look on [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/5WUJbAgLj4Y)

Answer (score 0):

Add two lines in your textview:

```
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
```

Your code like :

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_tag_name"
        />
```